# When someone creates drama where it didnt exist?

Tags: phrase-requests, pejorative-language

My friend uses phrases to belittle me when I provide suggestions as to what his friend should order on the menu at a restaurant, he says things like,"He's a big boy let him decide" or "stay out of it". What word or phrase would you use to describe this behavior?

Comment: I don't think this is creating drama, per se, as your question asks. Instead, it seems to be an example of negation or belittling of yourself. You might consider a new boyfriend, as this is not the sort of thing that gets better.

Comment: If you want to describe your boyfriend in a pejorative manner....maybe time to look for another guy. Apart from that..."drama queen"? This sounds more like a rant, than a real question. Look for couples counseling.

Comment: In a general way, a person who always makes things difficult can be called a "trouble-maker" Your situation sounds more like emotional games though(bad types)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a single word, you could describe this person as being **captious**.

> marked by an often ill-natured inclination to stress faults and raise objections

- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/captious)

Example sentence:

> Ms. Jackson’s Lena, for example, is not the customary tower of saintly strength. She can be a **captious** and irritable mother-in-law to Ruth, and you feel the friction between the dominating women in Walter’s life.

- [*The New York Times*](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/04/04/theater/raisin-in-the-sun-brings-denzel-washington-back-to-broadway.html)

Also see the *New York Times* "word of the day" [entry on captious.](https://mobile.nytimes.com/blogs/learning/2016/08/09/word-of-the-day-quiz-captious/?mcubz=1)

Comment: +1 I like this example. There might be others but this seems do capture what she wanted.

Comment: +1 because it's a good word that I didn't even know.  :-)